# I cannot determine error in my android application

Tags: android, api, gps, maps

How can I make android phone download the maps from the wi-fi internet but not from 3G internet? I have set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` but I still see only grid gray lines when I install and start app on actual phone. When i start the app on the emulator it loads flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Key is associcated with the keystore.
Make sure that the device is also using the same keystore that emulator is using, otherwise you will need another API Key.

Comment: I have stored here C:\android\debug.keystore, so I have to add this dir to CUSTOM DEBUG KEYSTORE field? Because when i was obtaining the API key I copied debug.keystor in C:\android

Comment: Or when exporting the app for use on the actual phone i need to use the same debug.keystore?

Answer (score 0):

hi carefully reaf [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)

u can get all answere from there. in your current prob u have to add Maps API Key on your android manifest.xml file.